# Is there a replacement for auto_ptr that can be used with boost ptr_map in c++11

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

In c++11 `auto_ptr` is deprecated and replaced with the more sensible `unique_ptr`. Alas if you use `boost::ptr_map` the `auto_ptr` fulfilled a very handy use:

```
std::auto_ptr<Layer> pLayer(new Layer());
mRawLayerPtrMap.insert(layerName,pLayer);
```

Is there a possibility to use something similar with c++11.
I know that

```
Layer* pLayer = new Layer();
mFusedLayers.insert(fusedLayerName,pLayer);
```

works but the `auto_ptr` had it's merits in some more complicated scenarios.
Is there a replacement that works with C++11 ?

Comment: What exactly prevents you from using unique_ptr?

Comment: boost has no insert function for it, at least not in 1.46 and as far as documented not in the newer versions, but I have not checked in the sources

Comment: Looking at the boost documentation on the motivation for ptr_map It looks like there's no reason to use that in place of a regular map with unique_ptr.

Comment: I am sure one day boost will support it.

Comment: @bames53: There is: Addressing a ptr_map element goes by reference not by pointer, which has its merrits for readability and safety

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
std::unique_ptr<Layer> pLayer(new Layer());
mFusedLayers.insert(fusedLayerName,pLayer.release());
```

Comment: Works fine thanks. Even mFusedLayers.insert(fusedLayerName,std::unique_ptr<Layer>(new Layer()).release()); goes down well

Comment: @LokiAstari True that works as well. Would there be a difference in things happening behind the scenes in this case?

Comment: `unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr(T*)` is explicit, you have to use direct initialization.

Comment: Note:  that is not exception safe.  If insert throws, the object will be leaked.  Better to write it as:

std::unique_ptr<Layer> pLayer(new Layer());
mFusedLayers.insert(fusedLayerName,pLayer.get());
pLayer.release();

Comment: Shouldn't it be: 
std::unique_ptr<Layer> pLayer(new Layer(mLayers,mames,fName));
bool inserted = mFusedLayers.insert(fName,pLayer.get()).second;   if(inserted) pLayer.release(); To make sure the element was inserted

Comment: @Nevin: No, ownership is transferred to `insert`.  If `insert` throws, it will also delete the object.